# OPNsense move interface to other hardware port

Tags: networking, opnsense

I have an OPNsense with interfaces directy configured to the hardware ports. The corresponding switch port is also an access port.

We plan to change the switch port to a trunk port to transport multiple VLANs via this port. Is there a way to move the already configured OPNsense interface (IPs, rules, etc.) to the new corresponding vlan port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out.

1. Add the VLAN interface to the hardware port via "Other Types"
2. Change the FW interface assignment to the VLAN interface at "Assignments"
3. Reboot to flush and recreate the state table
4. In case of a cluster, start with the passive host and do a CARP Switch Over.